# Why would this line throw exception for type initializer failed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I had a class:

```
public class Constant
{

    public static string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

which would throw exception on LIVE: Type initialize failed for Constant ctor

If I change the class to:

```
public class Constant
{
    public static string ConnString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

it works. I wasted 2 hours behind this but I still don't know why would this happen. Any ideas?

**Note:** The 1st class used to work on DEV environment but not on LIVE. The 2nd class works on DEV and also on Production.

I am using VS2010 on production and Asp.Net 4.0 Website project.

I am totally amazed by this inconsistency to say the least!

**Edit:** This class was in `App_Code` folder.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? It's likely to make it easier to work out what's going on. I have a suspicion, but I'd like to see a stack trace first...

Comment: When `TypeInitializationException` is thrown, the `InnerException` provides additional information about the cause of the exception. Are you able to examine the inner exception?

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, no stacktrace available :(. For that I will have to again publish on it as I forgot to record the stacktrace. But it contained some exeption of button_click and then CheckUsername which in turned used this property. This was all in stacktrace. No other meaningful information.

Comment: @Jon: And by the way, this class was in App_Code. Just telling if it can be of any help to you.

Comment: @Jaggu, you said:
"It is only today this issue started coming when I added few features and published." What features did you add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main difference is:

- The first one is computed when `Constant` class is initialized
- The second is evaluated first time `ConnString` property is accessed (so probably initialization phase is complete)

Comment: The first will only be evaluated when the `Constant` class is initialized, which is unlikely to be at the start of the program execution. It's likely to be triggered by *some* sort of reference to it.

Comment: @Jon: You are correct. I am accessing it on page inside button_click of asp:button. It is unlikely that ConfigurationManager is not initialized at that point.

Comment: @Jaggu: do you have some other code inside Constant class that can be called during program start?

Comment: @Marco: No it is a helper class. The ConnString is accessed in button_click. If I tried to load a page which didn't use this property it would work well. If I tried accessing this property it would throw this exception. I thought it must be some temporary files issue. I deleted everything and published the website for more than 6 times :p before I found that issue was something else. To further amaze you, this is the same website which was working previously and this class has been there on live for 3-4 months. It is only today this issue started coming when I added few features and published.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this line

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString
```

will throw an exception on LIVE.

In the first case however this happens in your class constructor so the type initialization fails.

In the second case the exception is delayed until you use the property.

Answer (score 0):

It may well be that for whatever reason, the ConfigurationManager wasn't initialised when Constant was initialised in the first example. However, Class 2 will go and fetch the property in ConfigurationManager when it's actually needed, rather than when your Constant class is initialised.